# Only allow image uploads

Tags: php, file-upload

I know there are more image types than what I've found but I can't find them anywhere.
Here's what I have so far. I want to allow **all** image file types that can be displayed using the img tag. I remember there being a weird one for jpegs in IE or something. Does anyone know of the type I'm talking about or know where I can find a list of them?

e.g. .png .jpeg .jpg and .gif

```
"image/gif"
"image/jpeg"
"image/png"
```

Comment: You could start your research by examining the types PHP can natively detect: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php What image types browsers support may vary very widely though.

Comment: google: image mimetypes

Comment: I did use the search and I couldn't find anything. Either I wasn't searching correctly or they aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Andrej please write it as an answer so I can select it as the correct one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I only allow certain filetypes on upload in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486329/how-can-i-only-allow-certain-filetypes-on-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats

the information inside the actual image that determines the type. (mime-types)

http://site.com/image.php?name=file'> could actually render an image